# How can I reduce the RUs cost of count in cosmos db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Seems that querying for a COUNT in a cosmos db collection is more expensive as the number of rows that it counts in a linear fashion.

So when we count using a filter that that results in 10 it is about 4 RUs.
But when the filter is changed and the result is 10k it is 350 RUs.

Sample count query we use:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE c.type == "mytype" and c.partition == "mypartition"
```

Note: it is all in the same partition.

Are we missing something? Is there a way to improve this cost?

RUs cost is almost the same if we return the documents instead of just their count.

## UPDATE:

Metrics on the different queries based on the count result:

**Count: 9518**

```
Retrieved Document Count                 :           9,518
Retrieved Document Size                  :       8,285,200 bytes
Output Document Count                    :               1
Output Document Size                     :              53 bytes
Index Utilization                        :            0.00 %
Total Query Execution Time               :           92.01 milliseconds
  Query Preparation Times
    Query Compilation Time               :            0.10 milliseconds
    Logical Plan Build Time              :            0.06 milliseconds
    Physical Plan Build Time             :            0.05 milliseconds
    Query Optimization Time              :            0.00 milliseconds
  Index Lookup Time                      :            0.15 milliseconds
  Document Load Time                     :           61.74 milliseconds
  Runtime Execution Times
    Query Engine Execution Time          :           29.66 milliseconds
    System Function Execution Time       :            0.00 milliseconds
    User-defined Function Execution Time :            0.00 milliseconds
  Document Write Time                    :            0.01 milliseconds
  Client Side Metrics
    Retry Count                          :               0
    Request Charge                       :          319.42 RUs

  Partition Execution Timeline
  ┌────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┐
  │Partition Id│Start Time (UTC)│End Time (UTC) │Duration (ms)     │Number of Documents│Retry Count│
  ├────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┤
  │           0│ 01:04:32.263666│01:04:32.500449│            236.78│                  1│          0│
  └────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┘

  Scheduling Metrics
  ┌────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
  │Partition Id│Response Time (ms)  │Run Time (ms)       │Wait Time (ms)      │Turnaround Time (ms)│Number of Preemptions│
  ├────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
  │           0│               13.18│              236.50│               14.20│              250.70│                    1│
  └────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

**Count: 27**

```
Retrieved Document Count                 :              27
Retrieved Document Size                  :         100,813 bytes
Output Document Count                    :               1
Output Document Size                     :              51 bytes
Index Utilization                        :            3.70 %
Total Query Execution Time               :            1.29 milliseconds
  Query Preparation Times
    Query Compilation Time               :            0.14 milliseconds
    Logical Plan Build Time              :            0.05 milliseconds
    Physical Plan Build Time             :            0.05 milliseconds
    Query Optimization Time              :            0.01 milliseconds
  Index Lookup Time                      :            0.15 milliseconds
  Document Load Time                     :            0.55 milliseconds
  Runtime Execution Times
    Query Engine Execution Time          :            0.13 milliseconds
    System Function Execution Time       :            0.00 milliseconds
    User-defined Function Execution Time :            0.00 milliseconds
  Document Write Time                    :            0.01 milliseconds
  Client Side Metrics
    Retry Count                          :               0
    Request Charge                       :            4.46 RUs

  Partition Execution Timeline
  ┌────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────┐
  │Partition Id│Start Time (UTC)│End Time (UTC) │Duration (ms)     │Number of Documents│Retry Count│
  ├────────────┼────────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────┤
  │           0│ 01:04:50.216685│01:04:50.369771│            153.09│                  1│          0│
  └────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────┘

  Scheduling Metrics
  ┌────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
  │Partition Id│Response Time (ms)  │Run Time (ms)       │Wait Time (ms)      │Turnaround Time (ms)│Number of Preemptions│
  ├────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
  │           0│               13.97│              152.79│               14.95│              167.74│                    1│
  └────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Hey Amit. Mind sharing the query plan to compare the two queries? That can usually shine a light on the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics

Comment: Thanks Chris, I've updated the question with the metrics.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this @AmitApple?